# sql import xml file with multiple nodes/children

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

I'm trying to import the following XML file which contains multiple nodes on the same ID. It's a GPS output from a car (id and name). The file contains a node TripItemEntities which contains multiple TripItemEntity.

### GeoBewegingen.xml (file to import)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResponse xmlns="http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices">
            <TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResult>
                <TripOverviewEntity>
                    <Vehicle>
                        <Id>a58f2d56-2b07-41d4-ada1-00a7ca934868</Id>
                        <Name>1SNG489</Name>
                    </Vehicle>
                    <FromDateUtc>2017-09-28T22:00:00</FromDateUtc>
                    <ToDateUtc>2017-09-29T21:59:59</ToDateUtc>
                    <FromDateLocal>2017-09-29T00:00:00</FromDateLocal>
                    <ToDateLocal>2017-09-29T23:59:59</ToDateLocal>
                    <TripItemEntities>
                        <TripItemEntity>
                            <FromDateUtc>2017-09-28T22:00:00</FromDateUtc>
                            <ToDateUtc>2017-09-29T03:58:21</ToDateUtc>
                            <FromDateLocal>2017-09-29T00:00:00</FromDateLocal>
                            <ToDateLocal>2017-09-29T05:58:21</ToDateLocal>
                            <FromLocation>
                                <Address>
                                    <Street>Merkenveld</Street>
                                    <HouseNumber>31</HouseNumber>
                                    <PostalCode>2870</PostalCode>
                                    <City>Puurs</City>
                                    <Submunicipality>Puurs</Submunicipality>
                                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                                </Address>
                                <Longitude>4.28923606872559</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>51.0761642456055</Latitude>
                            </FromLocation>
                            <ToLocation>
                                <Address>
                                    <Street>Merkenveld</Street>
                                    <HouseNumber>31</HouseNumber>
                                    <PostalCode>2870</PostalCode>
                                    <City>Puurs</City>
                                    <Submunicipality>Puurs</Submunicipality>
                                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                                </Address>
                                <Longitude>4.28923606872559</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>51.0761642456055</Latitude>
                            </ToLocation>
                            <Type>StandStill</Type>
                            <FromPois />
                            <ToPois />
                            <MileageDriven>0</MileageDriven>
                            <MileageBirdFlight>0</MileageBirdFlight>
                            <Users />
                        </TripItemEntity>
                        <TripItemEntity>
                            <FromDateUtc>2017-09-29T03:58:21</FromDateUtc>
                            <ToDateUtc>2017-09-29T04:43:21</ToDateUtc>
                            <FromDateLocal>2017-09-29T05:58:21</FromDateLocal>
                            <ToDateLocal>2017-09-29T06:43:21</ToDateLocal>
                            <FromLocation>
                                <Address>
                                    <Street>Merkenveld</Street>
                                    <HouseNumber>31</HouseNumber>
                                    <PostalCode>2870</PostalCode>
                                    <City>Puurs</City>
                                    <Submunicipality>Puurs</Submunicipality>
                                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                                </Address>
                                <Longitude>4.28923606872559</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>51.0761642456055</Latitude>
                            </FromLocation>
                            <ToLocation>
                                <Address>
                                    <Street>Hazopweg</Street>
                                    <PostalCode>9130</PostalCode>
                                    <City>Beveren</City>
                                    <Submunicipality>Kallo</Submunicipality>
                                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                                </Address>
                                <Longitude>4.22500610351563</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>51.2515640258789</Latitude>
                            </ToLocation>
                            <Type>Driving</Type>
                            <FromPois />
                            <ToPois />
                            <MileageDriven>26.60009765625</MileageDriven>
                            <MileageBirdFlight>20.0111999723037</MileageBirdFlight>
                            <Users>
                                <UserEntity>
                                    <Id>60f0691d-8348-42cf-8ce9-2e1744b0115e</Id>
                                    <Name>Thomas Jacobs</Name>
                                    <DayProgramId xsi:nil="true" />
                                </UserEntity>
                            </Users>
                        </TripItemEntity>
                    </TripItemEntities>
                </TripOverviewEntity>
            </TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResult>
        </TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following SQL to import the XML, but i only get the first TripItemEntity, not the rest.

### SQL Query

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\GeoDynamics\Downloads\GeoBewegingen.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices')
INSERT INTO GeoBewegingen(Id,voernaam,voercode,pervan,pertot,tripvan,triptot,tripvanlocstr,tripvanlocnr,tripvanlocpc,tripvanloccity,tripvanlocsub,tripvanloccountry,tripvanlong,tripvanlat,tripnaarlocstr,tripnaarlocnr,tripnaarlocpc,tripnaarloccity,tripnaarlocsub,tripnaarloccountry,tripnaarlong,tripnaarlat,triptype,tripkmgereden,tripkmvogelvlucht,tripuserid,tripusername)
SELECT
    Id = resource.value('(Vehicle/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    voernaam = resource.value('(Vehicle/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    voercode = resource.value('(Vehicle/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    pervan = resource.value('(FromDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    pertot = resource.value('(ToDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvan = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    triptot = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocstr = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/Street)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocnr = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/HouseNumber)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocpc = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanloccity = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/City)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocsub = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/Submunicipality)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanloccountry = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Address/Country)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlong = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Longitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlat = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/FromLocation/Latitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocstr = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/Street)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocnr = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/HouseNumber)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocpc = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarloccity = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/City)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocsub = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/Submunicipality)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarloccountry = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Address/Country)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlong = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Longitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlat = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/ToLocation/Latitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    triptype = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/Type)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripkmgereden = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/MileageDriven)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripkmvogelvlucht = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/MileageBirdFlight)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripuserid = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/Users/UserEntity/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripusername = resource.value('(TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity/Users/UserEntity/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResponse/TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResult/TripOverviewEntity') AS XTbl1(resource)
```

How can i import the rest of the TripItemEntity in the file?

Comment: it's SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use path of repeated nodes in `nodes` function.

In this question the path should be `//TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResponse/TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResult/TripOverviewEntity/TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity`

Fixed query:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\GeoBewegingen.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices')
INSERT INTO GeoBewegingen(Id,voernaam,voercode,pervan,pertot,tripvan,triptot,tripvanlocstr,tripvanlocnr,tripvanlocpc,tripvanloccity,tripvanlocsub,tripvanloccountry,tripvanlong,tripvanlat,tripnaarlocstr,tripnaarlocnr,tripnaarlocpc,tripnaarloccity,tripnaarlocsub,tripnaarloccountry,tripnaarlong,tripnaarlat,triptype,tripkmgereden,tripkmvogelvlucht,tripuserid,tripusername)
SELECT
    Id = resource.value('(../../Vehicle/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    voernaam = resource.value('(../../Vehicle/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    voercode = resource.value('(../../Vehicle/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    pervan = resource.value('(../../FromDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    pertot = resource.value('(../../ToDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvan = resource.value('(../../FromDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    triptot = resource.value('(../../ToDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocstr = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/Street)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocnr = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/HouseNumber)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocpc = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanloccity = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/City)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlocsub = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/Submunicipality)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanloccountry = resource.value('(FromLocation/Address/Country)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlong = resource.value('(FromLocation/Longitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripvanlat = resource.value('(FromLocation/Latitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocstr = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/Street)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocnr = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/HouseNumber)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocpc = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarloccity = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/City)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlocsub = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/Submunicipality)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarloccountry = resource.value('(ToLocation/Address/Country)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlong = resource.value('(ToLocation/Longitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripnaarlat = resource.value('(ToLocation/Latitude)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    triptype = resource.value('(Type)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripkmgereden = resource.value('(MileageDriven)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripkmvogelvlucht = resource.value('(MileageBirdFlight)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripuserid = resource.value('(Users/UserEntity/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    tripusername = resource.value('(Users/UserEntity/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResponse/TripOverview_GetByVehicleIdListDateResult/TripOverviewEntity/TripItemEntities/TripItemEntity') AS XTbl1(resource)
```

Comment: Hi Sarslan, your changes seem to work, but how can i do the import multiple times to update the values? Now every time i run the query it's adds new values. There is no unique id in the table. The only unique could be the id and tripvan. These two fields combined are allways unique.

Comment: you can add this query to where part of it.`WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM GeoBewegingen WHERE 
 Id = resource.value('(../../Vehicle/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
 AND tripvan = resource.value('(../../FromDateLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'))`

Comment: I got that also, but the query takes 2min to execute. The original file contains 550 records and the sql server is brand new with enterprise ssd's . It must be the way the query is build up. I will mark your comment as the answer since you have answered correctly. I would appreciate if you knew how to speed it up? :)

Comment: Do you have index on Id and tripvan columns?

Comment: Can you create an index with this script and try again? `CREATE INDEX IX_GeoBewegingen_Id_tripvan ON GeoBewegingen(Id, tripvan)`

Comment: still very slow, the index doesn't have any effect on the query

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any further advice. Maybe you can check execution plan for determine most time consuming part.